Google Ads not pulling data from Bigquery (Trying to upload customer list to audiences)
I'm trying to upload all customer data from BigQuery into Google Ads to improve our customer match on audiences.
I was able to make the integration, but for some reason I'm getting an unknown error and no data is being pulled.
Runs results
Error Details or lack of ...
This is the data we are sending, we have followed the requested format and not doing any data transformation to avoid weird issues.
I'm a bit lost on what else I should be checking on this - and I felt like google ads gives more instructions on how to upload CSV data rather than how to automate with BigQuery.
Anyone been through this or has any ideas?
Field Mapping
Thanks in advance :)
